# Objective-C : Why is my retain count not 1?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-management

I have this very simple program where I just create an object and look at the retain count.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GeometryCalculator.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
     NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

     GeometryCalculator *calculator = [[GeometryCalculator alloc] init];
     NSLog(@"Counter: %d", [calculator retainCount]);

    [calculator release];

        [pool drain];
        return 0;  
}
```

I expected my retainCount to be 1 but it is 16863520.
The Class GeometryCalculator is totally empty. No methodes, no instance variables.

Comment: Does your GeometryCalculator inherit from NSObject?

Comment: KennyTM: If it didn't, then the calculator would not respond to `retainCount`, and the message would cause an exception, not return garbage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are testing this with garbage collection enabled. The result of `retainCount` is undefined under garbage collection, but in practical terms, it returns the pointer value of your object because that’s the fastest undefined thing to do (in this case, `0x1015120`).

(Trivia: you’re also testing in a 32-bit process. If it was a 64-bit process, you’d get the high word of the pointer because of the type truncation Peter refers to, and that would be a lower value.)

Comment: Yes I had the Garbage Collector enabled. I was playing around with the setting the day before and totally forgot about it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The correct type specifier is `%lu`, not `%d`. The `retainCount` method returns `NSUInteger`, which is unsigned and equal in size to a `long`—so, practically, it's equivalent to `unsigned long`, for which you use `%lu`. `%d` is `int`, which is signed and (on some architectures) shorter. Using wrong type specifiers is a good way to get wrong output. So, see whether fixing that corrects your output.

If it doesn't, then this is certainly a puzzle.